# before delete trigger before deleting particular user_id

Tags: postgresql, triggers

```
Note management app (similar to Google Keep) is used to take notes, add notes into categories and set reminders for a note. Create the necessary DB schema including tables, relationships, triggers and add sample data into each table.
```

Create a trigger to delete all matching records from UserNote, NoteReminder and NoteCategory table when : 1. A particular note is deleted from Note table (all the matching records from UserNote, NoteReminder and NoteCategory should be removed automatically) 2. A particular user is deleted from User table (all the matching notes should be removed automatically)

Comment: Why the `postgresql` tag if you are using MySQL?

Comment: Look up the option `on delete cascade` for foreign keys. No trigger required.